# $A\subset B$ implies that:

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A\subset B$ implies that:

$1$. $B\subset A$

$2$. $B'\subset A'$

$3$. $A'\subset B'$

$4$. $\textrm {None}$.

My Attempt:

Let $x$ be an element in set $B$.
$$x\in B$$
$$\implies x\in A$$

And,

$$x\notin B$$
$$\implies x\notin A$$

.

Comment: Your first implication is incorrect: $A\subset B$ definitely doesn't imply $B\subset A$.

Comment: @A---B, Complement of sets.

Comment: @AlbertEinstein But you wrote $x \in B \Longrightarrow x \in A$...

Comment: Is A' supposed to be complement?

Comment: @fleablood, yes it means complement.

Comment: How did you get the first implication. A is completely contained in B.  It's possible for B to contain elements not in A.  I'll be honest.  I find it very hard to understand how anyone can get a wrong answer on this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the prime $'$ indicate the complement of the set?

If so, then $A \subseteq B$ implies $B' \subseteq A'$. To see this, suppose $A \subseteq B$. Let $x \in B'$. Then $x \notin B$. Since $A \subseteq B$, $x \notin A$ (for if $x \in A$, then $x \in B$, contrary to $x \notin B'$). Then $x \in A'$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, $B' \subseteq A'$.

Comment: The book says the answer is $3$???

Comment: Are you sure that the prime $'$ indicates complementation and not, say, the set of all accumulation points or something?

Comment: *If* the prime $'$ denotes complementation, then the book's answer is incorrect. For instance, take $U$ to be the universal set of discourse. Let $A = \varnothing$ and $B = U$. Clearly, $A \subseteq B$. Then $A' = U$ and $B' = \varnothing$, so clearly $A'$ is *not* a subset of $B'$.

Comment: (With $U$ nonempty.)

Answer (score 1):

As an example to show why $A\subset B$ does not mean $x\in B\implies x\in A$:

Consider $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{1,2\}$. Then $2\in B$ but $2\notin A$.

---

Now for the right answer (assuming $A'$ means the complement of $A$; if not, then I'll edit the question later):

$$x\notin A \implies x\in A'$$

Then you have two cases:

- $x\notin B$ and $x\notin A$: Then $x\in B'$ and $x\in A'$
- $x\in B$ but $x\notin A$: Then we still have $x \in A'$ but $x\notin B'$

Then in general $B'\subset A'$, since we have more elements in $A'$ than in $B'$